# Lossless conversion of NSDate to NSString and vice versa

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have an NSDate:

> 2015-07-13 16:04:01 +0000

and I want to convert it to an NSString to be able to store it on a server and then read it back from server and convert back to NSDate without losing any details.

I've been looking at other posts that have suggested doing it as follows:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

and vice-versa:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:message[@"date"]];
```

but this leads to the loss and compromise of the format:

> Jul 13, 2015

How do I convert NSDate to NSString and back, eventually getting back the exact original NSDate?

Comment: You make the date formatter's [format](http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/) capture all units you want it to capture?

Comment: `NSDateFormatterMediumStyle` : `Specifies a medium style, typically with abbreviated text, such as “Nov 23, 1937” or “3:30:32 PM”.` are you sure that fits the string you read in?

Comment: Does it have to be a string? Could it be some other type?

Comment: What exactly do you want to store in the database and how exactly are you trying to extract that given data - what is not working? "leads to the loss and compromise of the format" is not really a good description of whats going wrong.

Comment: @Christian, I want a complete replica of my NSDate with a NSString - so I need to capture everything, how do I do that?

Comment: @luk2302 - that's my question - how do I specify an exact replica format

Comment: @etayluz It depends on what *everything* is in your very context. I can think of no context where *everything* is what you really want. `NSDate` is nothing but a floating point number internally, so there are inaccuracies in smaller units anyway. Ask yourself the question: Which units am I interested in? And then build a format string using the link I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only formatting the original `NSDate` with a date (not time) style that reflects the user's preferences and you're only formatting the retrieved `NSDate` with day, month, and year, i.e. "dd-MM-yyyy". You should be consistent your `NSDateFormatter`s in order to maintain the original format.

Change both

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
```

and

```
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
```

to

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
```

to get and keep the entire date and time format.

Comment: How do I convert NSDate to NSString while retaining all information inside the NSDate?

Comment: @etayluz Updated to explain.

Comment: This is correct, though it leads to conversion of time zone from "2015-07-13 16:44:02 +0000" to "2015-07-13 11:44:02 -0500"

Comment: @etayluz NSDates are always in GMT time zone. But if you want to set the keep the string in GMT time zone, you have to specify that with your NSDateFormatter: `[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]]`;

Comment: awesome, tnx! You're a genius!

Comment: This is not completely lossless. Milliseconds will be lost. To preserve milliseconds, add .SSS after the ss.

Answer (score 1):

An NSDate stores the number of seconds since a reference date. If you are using only iOS applications. then you call a method returning that number of seconds as an NSTimeInterval which is a number, and then you store the number. This means there is absolutely no loss of information. Your data will come back with better than microsecond precision.

If the data has to be read by different devices not running iOS then there is another method returning the number of seconds since Jan 1st, 1970. This is a very standard format that any OS should be able to handle.

Storing a number instead of a string seems to be much better.

Comment: Could you share how to fetch the seconds from NSDate and then convert back?